# Get Instagram post contents php

Tags: php, instagram

I want to develop a PHP project for getting the content of an Instagram post (via the post URL). I mean, for example, the crawler getting this [Url](https://www.instagram.com/p/BX6IowXFbq9/?hl=en) and returning :

```
#TBT Used to love carrying them both at once #twinmom #mycoconuts 
#mylifeinmyhands #toobignow #istilltrysometimes #LOVE #forevermybabies
```

After I used the file_get_contents, the  of returned response is empty. I don't know how to fix this problem. Can you help me?

I don't want to use the Instagram API!

Comment: you cant get the page details using file get contents function. As the page / post is loaded via javascript after page load ( try opening page in javascript disabled browser window). There is no other way of getting the page contents other than using their api

Comment: Instagram is a React app, which means that lots of stuff are happening client-side. The only viable solution is consuming their API. There are a few PHP libraries as well eg. https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use this since it will break as soon as Instagram makes a change to their markup, but here you go:

```
<?php

$instagram_url = "https://www.instagram.com/p/BX6IowXFbq9";

$source = file_get_contents($instagram_url);

preg_match('/<script type="text\/javascript">window\._sharedData =([^;]+);<\/script>/', $source, $matches);

$data = json_decode($matches[1]);

echo $data->entry_data->PostPage[0]->graphql->shortcode_media->edge_media_to_caption->edges[0]->node->text;
```

Comment: Does not work anymore

Comment: @MehdiGolzadeh it still does, you just need to update the $instagram_url.

Answer (score 0):

This is little late but I am able to fetch Instagram timeline, Specific Media Details.

E.g:

- Fetch user's list of post

If Instagram User page url is https://www.instagram.com/marvel then to fetch this page data you can use below URL

```
https://www.instagram.com/marvel?__a=1
```

- Fetch specific media post details

If Instagram post detail page url is https://www.instagram.com/p/BfeD8RxHwnC/?taken-by=marvel then to fetch this page data you can use below URL

```
https://www.instagram.com/p/BfeD8RxHwnC/?taken-by=marvel&__a=1
```